# vue.js load script from cdn and then component vue (without webpack)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How can i load the custom script from cdn in the component. So that i can use `myScript.abc()` in the load method.

```
Vue.component('example', {

   // LOAD ANOTHER SCIPT : SAY cdn.myScript

    // render function as alternative to 'template'
    render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement(
            // {String | Object | Function}
            // An HTML tag name, component options, or function
            // returning one of these. Required.
            'h2',
            // {Object}
            // A data object corresponding to the attributes
            // you would use in a template. Optional.
            {
                style: {
                    color: 'red', 
                },
                domProps: {
                    innerHTML: 'My Example Header'
                }
            },

    )},
    methods:{
      a:function(z){
         myScript.hello();
      }
    } 
});
```

This is loaded via vue-router.
And not using vue-loader or webpack

How to load my custom script.
Any link to documentation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
    beforeMount(){
      this.scriptLoader('some/url').then(() => {
        this.a();
      }, error => {
        console.error('Failed to load script', error.target.src)
      })
    },
    methods:{
      a:function(){
         myScript.hello();
      }
      scriptLoader: function(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const existing = document.querySelector('script#someUniqueId');
          if (existing) existing.remove();
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          script.onload = () => {
            resolve();
          };
          script.onerror = e => {
            reject(e);
          };
          script.id = 'someUniqueId';
          script.async = true;
          script.src = url;
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        })
      }
    }
```

Let's try it out...

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeMount() {
    this.scriptLoader('https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/assets/_build/js/lib/particles.js').then(() => {
      this.a();
    }, e => console.error('Failed to load script', e.target.src))
  },
  methods: {
    a: function() {
      particlesJS("particles-js", {
        particles: {
          number: {
            value: 80,
            density: {
              enable: true,
              value_area: 840
            }
          },
          color: {
            value: "#ffffff"
          },
          shape: {
            type: "triangle",
            stroke: {
              width: 0,
              color: "#000000"
            },
            polygon: {
              nb_sides: 42
            },
          },
          opacity: {
            value: 0.42,
            random: false,
            anim: {
              enable: false,
              speed: 1,
              opacity_min: 0.1,
              sync: false
            }
          },
          size: {
            value: 3,
            random: true,
            anim: {
              enable: false,
              speed: 42,
              size_min: 0.1,
              sync: false
            }
          },
          line_linked: {
            enable: true,
            distance: 210,
            color: "#ffffff",
            opacity: 0.42,
            width: 1
          },
          move: {
            enable: true,
            speed: 4.2,
            direction: "none",
            random: true,
            straight: false,
            out_mode: "out",
            bounce: false,
            attract: {
              enable: false,
              rotateX: 600,
              rotateY: 1200
            }
          }
        },
        interactivity: {
          detect_on: "canvas",
          events: {
            onhover: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "repulse"
            },
            onclick: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "push"
            },
            resize: true
          },
          modes: {
            grab: {
              distance: 420,
              line_linked: {
                opacity: 1
              }
            },
            bubble: {
              distance: 420,
              size: 42,
              duration: 2.1,
              opacity: 8.4,
              speed: 3
            },
            repulse: {
              distance: 84,
              duration: 0.84
            },
            push: {
              particles_nb: 4.2
            },
            remove: {
              particles_nb: 2.1
            }
          }
        },
        retina_detect: true
      });
    },
    scriptLoader: function(url) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const existing = document.querySelector('script#particlesJs');
        if (existing) {
            existing.remove();
        }
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = () => {
          resolve();
        };
        script.onerror = e => {
          reject(e);
        }
        script.id = 'particlesJs';
        script.async = true;
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
</div>
```

And with an error:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeMount() {
    this.scriptLoader('//some/bogus/link/particles.js').then(() => {
      this.a();
    }, e => console.error('Failed to load resource from', e.target.src))
  },
  methods: {
    a: function() {},
    scriptLoader: function(url) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const existing = document.querySelector('script#particlesJs');
        if (existing) {
            existing.remove();
        }
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = () => {
          resolve();
        };
        script.onerror = e => {
          reject(e);
        }
        script.id = 'particlesJs';
        script.async = true;
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
</div>
```

**Note** on `if (existing) existing.remove();`

This guards against appending the same `<script>` multiple times.
In many cases, where the resource doesn't expire (or the expiry is irrelevant), you might want to skip script reload if it was already appended. i.e.: `if(!existing) { /* append the script */ }`.

By removing the previously appended `<script>` and adding it again we're passing the expiry evaluation to the browser and, subsequently, to the server serving the resource.

If the resource has not expired, the browser will serve it from cache, without making a new request to the server.
If it expired, it will be requested again and the updated version will be served (useful when dealing with volatile resources).

---

I'd be tempted to move this method from a Vue component into a service and import it where needed, rather than have it defined in each instance of that particular component.